# Displaying image stored in ostrio:files

Tags: file, reactjs, meteor, collections

In ostrio:files docs used `findOne` function, that is not convinient in my case, I need `find()` with parameters to filter by user id and so on.
I use common Meteor React approach from official tutorial as follows:

```jsx
renderImages(){
    return this.props.images.map((image) => (
        <Pic src={image.link()} />
    ));
}

render() {
...
    return (
        <form>
            <FormGroup controlId="formControlsFile">
                <Media>
                    {this.renderImages()}
                </Media>
...
            </FormGroup>
        </form>);
    }
}

export default createContainer(props => {
    Meteor.subscribe("files.images.all");
    return {
        images: Images.find({name: "1.jpeg"}).fetch(),
    }
}, App);
```

Here is collection:

```js
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { FilesCollection } from 'meteor/ostrio:files';

const Images = new FilesCollection({
    collectionName: 'Images',
    allowClientCode: false, // Disallow remove files from Client
    onBeforeUpload(file) {
...
});

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish('files.images.all', function () {
        return Images.find().fetch();
    });
}

export default Images;
```

and Pic element:

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import {createContainer} from 'meteor/react-meteor-data'

class Pic extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <img width={64} height={64} src={this.props.src} alt="Image"/>
        );
    }
}

export default createContainer(props => {
    console.log("Image src: " + props.src);
    return {
        src: (props.src ? props.src : "no-image-64x64.jpg"),
    }
}, Pic);
```

This code causes the following exception:

```
I20170727-13:46:02.470(3)? Exception from sub files.images.all id uXo24fBLqH8rsMiDy Error: Publish function returned an array of non-Cursors
I20170727-13:46:02.472(3)?     at [object Object]._.extend._publishHandlerResult (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1098:20)
I20170727-13:46:02.472(3)?     at [object Object]._.extend._runHandler (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1060:10)
I20170727-13:46:02.473(3)?     at [object Object]._.extend._startSubscription (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:859:9)
I20170727-13:46:02.473(3)?     at [object Object]._.extend.protocol_handlers.sub (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:625:12)
I20170727-13:46:02.474(3)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:559:43
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two factors important two know:

**1. Return a cursor instead of array**

Your publish function needs to return a cursor, currently it returns an array (by calling fetch), which is no cursor.

You don't need fetch in the publication but on the client side. The publication is solely there to sync the client collection with the server collection by a given filter/transform/sort etc.

**2. You need to get the data from the Mongo.Collection and not the FilesCollection**

The FilesCollection itself is no collection but makes use of a Mongo.Collection. If you want to use the data from the collection, you need to reference the collection like so: `Images.collection.find`

**Example that returns a cursor:**

```js
Meteor.publish('files.images.all', function () {

    // find data and return cursor if
    // data exists
    const data = Images.collection.find();
    if (data && data.count() >0)
        return data;

    this.ready(); // set ready if no data exists
});
```

The same applies for your client:

```js
export default createContainer(props => {
    Meteor.subscribe("files.images.all");
    return {
        images: Images.collection.find({name: "1.jpeg"}).fetch(),
    }
}, App);
```

There is also more to read on the [ostrio:files documentation](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/wiki/collection)

Comment: Exactly the same exception((

Comment: Oh yes I forgot to mention, that you need to get the data from the collection and not the FilesCollection instance, I will update my answer

Comment: Partially works: shows "no-image". How get a stored image itself and pass it to src of <img>?

Comment: I think this would be a different question, since the ostrio:files package takes on different approaches and depending on the way you store your file in the backend (s3 vs. gridFs vs. Filesystem vs. etc.) there may be a totally different answer to it. You may go a bit deeper into the [documentation](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/wiki/React-Example) and ask with a new question here if you get stuck.

Edit: maybe you just need to add the relative path to your src attribute, assuming you store the images via your server's Filesystem and they are publicly available.

Comment: Files are stored locally, but image.link() doesn't work - no such function. Object from images collection contains relative with filename, but there is no such file in a file system.

Comment: The problem was that files were not uploaded. To get link() method I added second prop `Images.find()`